# Как научиться анализировать Heap Dump и Thread Dump?

Tags: java, jvm, heapdump

Хочу научиться находить по heap dump и thread dump утечни памяти, но не могу разобраться, как их анализировать. В интернете много статей о том, как сделать эти дампы, но почти ничего нет об анализе. Вот я сделал хип дамп:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как по этим данным определить строчку кода, где утекает память? Как то же самое сделать с тред дампом?

Comment: Очень актуальный вопрос. Я бы ещё дополнил (шкурный интерес): не обязательно "утекает", а вообще - кто вызвал потребление памяти. Вот, на скрине, например - больше всего занимают массивы байт. Как определить, кто их сделал и желательно - отфильтровать по "мой код / не мой код".

Comment: @kami не помню как реализовано конкретно в VisualVM, но обычно в инструментах для анализа хипдампов можно ткнуть в интересующий тип и (даблкликом/через контекстное меню или как-то еще) получить GC Roots.

Comment: @typemoon Это довольно творческая задача. Самое простое, что можно предпринять, это загрузить хипдамп в Eclipse Memory Analyzer и построить отчет по утечкам, он покажет подозрительные типы объектов и их GC roots. В остальном же: строить гипотезы, что может утекать и подтверждать или опровергать их через данные. Например, в отладчике IDEA можно снять хипдампы в нескольких временных точках, посмотреть на дельты количества и объема, найти долгоживущие объекты, подумать должны ли они жить так долго, и какие GC roots мешают сборщику мусора собрать их.

Comment: Можно в async-profiler собрать перевернутый flamechart с аллокациями, чтобы поискать горячие места и потенциальных кандидатов на утечку.